# Call MVC Controller Action with Multiple Parameters from Javascript Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm still learning while developing an ASP.net MVC website that uses datatables.net javascript to display users and then call controller actions with a set of buttons for each user.

I'd like to call an email controller and send both the user ID and the type of email being sent to that controller.  This will allow me to customize the email title, text, from address, etc. based on the email type.

I have the call working in datatables to send the Id without the type using this javscript to produce the anchor tag:

```
</a>
<a href="/admin/user/mEmail?id=${data.id}" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer; width:100px;">
    <i class="bi bi-send"></i>Email
</a>
```

The Controller action is pretty simple at this point:

```
 public IActionResult MEmail(string? id)
 {
     EmailVM objVM = new EmailVM
     {
         SendType = SD.EmailType_Membership,
         SendTo = _unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.Get(u => u.Id == id).Email,
         From= "Membership Management",
         MessageText = "Your membership application has been reviewed and will be approved when we receive your dues payment.",
         Subject = "Membership Application Processing"

     };
     return View(objVM);
 }
```

How do I add the type string as literal text to the anchor tag?  Will I be able to pick it up with  public IActionResult MEmail(string? id, string? type)?  Appreciate any help you can give me!

I tried several simple modification to the anchor tag with no luck and searched the web with no luck as well.

Comment: How is your Datatable created? Can you provide more code of it. If it is generated within asp.net you should be able to add the type to your query params after the ?. Like: .../mEmail?id=${data.id}&type=${data.type}

But you will have to add the type to your data bucket

Comment: The data table is generated using datatable.net scripts and a get API call to the MVC controller to get the data from the database.  Data is returned to the page in a Json list of users.   The type is really just a string that I'll use to distinguish the type of email that is being sent and not part of the data set...I think I can hack a solution in by concatenating the type with the user ID (a GUID) and then parsing it out in the controller, but was hoping there was a more elegant way to get there...

Comment: SirOneOfMany, Thanks for helping here, your answer works for literal string too formatted as Muhammad described below 'href="/admin/email/sendEmailToUser?id=${data.id}&type=Annual"   I've been shooting myself in the foot editing the wrong anchor tag today.  Thanks again!

Comment: haha yeah, there are those days

Answer (score 0):

To pass both the id and type parameters to your controller action, you can append the type parameter to the URL in your anchor tag. You can do this by adding it as a query parameter in the URL. Here's how you can modify your anchor tag:

```
<a href="/admin/user/mEmail?id=${data.id}&type=YourEmailTypeHere" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer; width:100px;">
<i class="bi bi-send"></i>Email
```

Replace "YourEmailTypeHere" with the actual value of your email type. This modification adds a query parameter type to the URL, and you can access it in your controller action.

Now, in your controller action, you can modify the method signature to accept both id and type parameters:

```
 
public IActionResult MEmail(string? id, string? type)
{
    // Your existing code here

    // Now you can use the 'type' parameter to customize your email further
    if (type == "YourEmailTypeHere")
    {
        // Customize email based on type
    }

    return View(objVM);
}
```

This way, both the id and type parameters will be passed to your controller action, and you can use them accordingly in your logic.

Comment: Muhammad, your answer is correct, my apologies!  I was editing the wrong anchor tag initially (there are two sets that might be displayed based on the locked/unlocked state of the user account).  Thank you very much!